# Formula for amplitude of X-ray diffraction through crystal

Tags: diffraction, x-rays, x-ray-crystallography

I’m an undergrad currently writing a report on a lab we’ve done using X-ray diffraction to look into the structure of crystals. We’ve been told that the structure factor of an element relates to the amplitude of diffraction, but not much more than ‘if it’s zero, you get no diffraction’.

I found a formula that seems to be where the use of the structure factor comes from:

$\phi_g = \frac{a_i \lambda F_g}{v_c \cos{\theta}}\sum{e^{-2\pi ikr_n}\cdot e^{2\pi ik_0r}}$

Can anyone give me any information on this equation? Or really all I need to know is what each variable means, so I can include it in the report. But some more information on it would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you expect anyone to be able to look at a random formula with no context and correctly explain every symbol? You should at least give a reference for where you got this formula from.